# Subscriptions Not Receiving Timeline Notifications

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Steps to Reproduce (unexpected behavior in **bold**):

1. I successfully create an app contact via the Python Starter App
2. I successfully subscribe to timeline notifications
3. I take a photo with Glass
4. I share that photo with my app contact
5. The photo is duplicated on the timeline
6. **The app's callbackUrl is never pinged (yet POSTing manually via curl works fine)**
7. **Attempting to delete the duplicated photo card makes the Glass OS glitch out until reboot**

Comment: That last sounds like a great bug report for Google, regardless of whether someone answers the question here.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: Last time we gave this a shot was 10/18.  Were there any known issues around this time?

Comment: Another great question for Google!

Comment: If you do a GET for the subscription collection (a list operation), what is the JSON in the response body?  Here's a snippet of Python that does a list: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/list#examples

Answer (score 0):

Posting some sample code with actual URLs may help us spot a possible error, but two things you may want to look into as you're debugging:

1. Don't forget that the URL in your contact must be HTTPS. HTTP URLs are **not** supported.
2. Check the contact object that is returned when you create the contact. It may be worth checking to make sure the URL and everything else is as you expect it to be... and then test against THAT URL.

Can you also clarify what you mean by "glitch out" in this case?

Comment: I have been trying, it is not working, i don't get share notification, it used to work (it worked intermittently once, then, it stopped working), any idea why? my glassware app is a .net app, i use client login token not oauth token, is it a issue?

Comment: @Snekithan - It sounds like this would best be asked as a separate question with its own examples and clarification, but the troubleshooting steps outlined above may help.